# Make text appear below boxes on another row on :hover?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a row of boxes which contain skills like so:
https://jsfiddle.net/7115213d/1/
The trouble I'm having is that when you hover over each one the text stays in one place and moves the other boxes below it, I have tried changing it to inline-block but that still messes up. I'd like to have it where when you hover over each individual box a block of text appears below it in the center on a new row, I did try this however it doesn't work once you take the "test message" onto a new row. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this or improve it? I am using a skeleton framework which consists of individual rows and columns. I have have looked everywhere and can not seem to find a solution so any help would be great.
Thanks

**HTML:**

```
        <div class="row">
                <div class="skill">
                    <div class="twelve columns">

                        <div id="skillimage">
                            <div class="box hvr-float">
                                <h1 class="php">PHP</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="hover">Test message</div>

                        <div id="skillimage">
                            <div class="box hvr-float">
                                <h1 class="css">CSS</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="hover">Test message</div>

                        <div id="skillimage">
                            <div class="box hvr-float">
                                <h1 class="html">HTML</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="hover">Test message</div>

                        <div id="skillimage">
                            <div class="box hvr-float">
                                <h1 class="photoshop">PS</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="hover">Test message</div>

                        <div id="skillimage">
                            <div class="box hvr-float">
                                <h1 class="js">JS</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="hover">Test message</div>



                            <div class="box hvr-float">
                                <h1 class="sql">SQL</h1>
                            </div> 
                            <div class="box hvr-float">
                                <h1 class="sass">SASS</h1>
                            </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>
```

**css**

```
 .box {
     display: inline-block;
     background-color: #424242;
     border-radius: 50px;
     height: 100px;
     width: 100px;
     margin: 14px;
 }
 .php {
     position: relative;
     top: 30px;
     padding: 0 10px;
     color: white;
     font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
     font-size: 30px;
     text-align: center;
 }
 .html {
     position: relative;
     top: 30px;
     color: white;
     font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
     font-size: 30px;
     text-align: center;
 }
 .css {
     position: relative;
     top: 30px;
     color: white;
     font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
     font-size: 30px;
     text-align: center;
 }
 .js {
     position: relative;
     top: 30px;
     color: white;
     font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
     font-size: 30px;
     text-align: center;
 }
 .photoshop {
     position: relative;
     top: 30px;
     color: white;
     font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
     font-size: 30px;
     text-align: center;
 }
 .sass {
     position: relative;
     top: 30px;
     color: white;
     font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
     font-size: 30px;
     text-align: center;
 }
 .sql {
     position: relative;
     top: 30px;
     color: white;
     font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
     font-size: 30px;
     text-align: center;
 }
 #skillimage {
     display: inline-block;
 }
 #hover {
     display: none;
 }
 #skillimage:hover + #hover {
     display: block;
 }
```

Comment: An `id` has to be unique inside a DOM tree. You will have to use classes for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this putting the `hover` div inside of `skillimage` like this

```css
.box{
        display:inline-block;
        background-color:#424242;
        border-radius:50px; 
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
        margin:14px;
}
    .php{
        position: relative;
        top: 30px;
        padding: 0 10px;
        color:white;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .html{
        position: relative;
        top: 30px;
       color:white;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .css{
        position: relative;
        top: 30px;
       color:white;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .js{
        position: relative;
        top: 30px;
        color:white;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .photoshop{
        position: relative;
        top: 30px;
        color:white;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align:center;
    }

.skillimage{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.hover {
    display: none;
}

.skillimage:hover  .hover {
    display: block;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
             <div class="skill">
                        <div class="twelve columns">
                            <div class="skillimage">
                                <div class="box hvr-float">
                                    <h1 class="php">PHP</h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hover">Test message</div>
                            </div>
                            
                            
                            <div class="skillimage">
                                <div class="box hvr-float">
                                    <h1 class="css">CSS</h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hover">Test message</div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="skillimage">
                                <div class="box hvr-float">
                                    <h1 class="html">HTML</h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hover">Test message</div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="skillimage">
                                <div class="box hvr-float">
                                    <h1 class="photoshop">PS</h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hover">Test message</div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="skillimage">
                                <div class="box hvr-float">
                                    <h1 class="js">JS</h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hover">Test message</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
```

Also, remember that an `id` must be unique in a DOM tree, so you have to set `hover` and `skillimage` as classes.